# Use global scss with storybook

Tags: javascript, storybook

I am new in Storybook.

I have a `.scss` file used in global. I want to import this file from storybook.

So I made .storybook/config.js file and import scss inside. but it shows me error.

### Error

```
ERROR in ./styles/style.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/style-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/sas
s-resources-loader/lib/loader.js!./styles/style.scss)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Invalid CSS after "v": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was 'var api = require("'
        on line 1 of C:\Users\Walter\WebstormProjects\closet-next\styles\style.scss
>> var api = require("!../node_modules/style-loader/dist/runtime/injectStylesIn
   ^

 @ ./styles/style.scss 2:26-346 43:4-64:5 46:18-338
 @ ./.storybook/config.js
 @ multi ./node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/common/polyfills.js ./node_modules/@storybook/core/dist/server/preview/globals.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-docs/dist/frameworks/common/config.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-docs/dist/frameworks/react/config.js ./.
storybook/config.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-knobs/dist/preset/addDecorator.js ./.storybook/generated-entry.js (webpack)-hot-middleware/client.js?reload=true&quiet=true
```

What is problem? Here is main.js

#### main.js

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  stories: ['../stories/**/*.stories.(js|mdx|tsx)'],
  addons: [
    '@storybook/addon-actions',
    '@storybook/addon-links',
    '@storybook/addon-knobs',
    '@storybook/preset-scss',
    {
      name: '@storybook/preset-typescript',
      options: {
        tsLoaderOptions: {
          configFile: path.resolve(__dirname, './tsconfig.json'),
        },
        forkTsCheckerWebpackPluginOptions: {
          colors: false, // disables built-in colors in logger messages
        },
        include: [path.resolve(__dirname, '/')],
        transpileManager: true,
      },
    },
    {
      name: '@storybook/addon-docs',
      options: {
        configureJSX: true, 
        babelOptions: {},

      },
    },
  ],
  parameters: {
    docs: {
      inlineStories: false, 
    },
  },
  webpackFinal: config => {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.scss$/,
      use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader', 'sass-loader', 'sass-resources-loader'],
    });
    return config;
  },
};
```

Answer (score 32):

Just add this line on the top of `.storybook/preview.js` then everything should be good

```
import '!style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader!../src/globalStyles/global.scss';
```

also remember to install dev dependencies

```
yarn add -D style-loader css-loader sass-loader
```

Comment: add `sass` also

Comment: i getting TypeError: this.getOptions is not a function please help to solve this

Comment: @KrishnaJangid check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66087132/2043718 ... also watch out for the version of css-loader and style.loader. You need to downgrade those versions due to "outdated" webpack version.

Comment: this.getOptions - Don't use sass-loader higher than 10, it requires webpack 5

Answer (score 4):

For `"@storybook/vue3": "^6.5.9"`, just import your styles in the `.storybook/preview.js`.

```js
import "../src/styles/app/_@index.scss"

export const parameters = {
  actions: { argTypesRegex: "^on[A-Z].*" },
  controls: {
    matchers: {
      color: /(background|color)$/i,
      date: /Date$/,
    },
  },
}
```

Here's my devDependencies in `package.json` for more info:

```js
"devDependencies": {
  "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.5.9",
  "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.5.9",
  "@storybook/addon-interactions": "^6.5.9",
  "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.5.9",
  "@storybook/builder-vite": "^0.1.36",
  "@storybook/testing-library": "0.0.13",
  "@storybook/vue3": "^6.5.9",
  "storybook-addon-sass-postcss": "^0.1.3",
}
```

Comment: For some reason it still cannot use anything from the scss imported in `preview.js`. It seems to regard the component as the root stylesheet and then just says it cannot find a variable defined in the `index.scss`. My devDependencies are the same as yours. any idea?

Comment: How could I dynamically import a different stylesheet based on a globals value?

Comment: @Taylor Have you tried using `import(cssPath)`?

Answer (score 1):

Which version of storybook are you using? `config.js` has been rename to `preview.js` [from v5.3 onwards](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/blob/next/MIGRATION.md#from-version-52x-to-53x)

To import global styles, you should create `.storybook/preview-head.html` and import your `global.scss` in there. This will load it for all the stories.

Comment: `global.scss` cannot be parsed by the browser and needs to be processed first. Are you implying that this step is implicitly  done by Storybook. If so is this documented somewhere? From my perspective I attempted the import but in vain.

Comment: I can see how my answer can be confusing. Sass files can of course not be imported in HTML files - they need to be preprocessed and the generated css file can only be included. I was more focussed on answering _where_ common styles for all stories can be included.

Answer (score 0):

From Storybook [documention](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/configure/webpack#extending-storybooks-webpack-config): How to add `scss` support

```js
// .storybook/main.js

const path = require('path');

// Export a function. Accept the base config as the only param.
module.exports = {
  webpackFinal: async (config, { configType }) => {
    // `configType` has a value of 'DEVELOPMENT' or 'PRODUCTION'
    // You can change the configuration based on that.
    // 'PRODUCTION' is used when building the static version of storybook.

    // Make whatever fine-grained changes you need
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.scss$/,
      use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
      include: path.resolve(__dirname, '../'),
    });

    // Return the altered config
    return config;
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The current [Storybook docs](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/addons/install-addons#using-preset-addons) recommend the following solution:

> Storybook preset addons are grouped collections of specific babel,webpack and addons configurations for distinct use cases. Each one with it's own set of instructions. Preset addons have a three-step installation process: install, register and optionally configuration.
>
> For example, to use SCSS styling, run the following command to install the addon and the required dependencies:
>
> ```
> # Webpack 5
>
> # With npm
> npm install @storybook/preset-scss css-loader sass sass-loader style-loader --save-dev
>
> # With yarn
> yarn add --dev @storybook/preset-scss css-loader sass sass-loader style-loader
> ```
>
> Next, update .storybook/main.js to the following:
>
> ```
> // .storybook/main.js
>
> module.exports = {
>   addons: ['@storybook/preset-scss'],
> };
> ```
>
> Now when you run Storybook it will configure itself to use SCSS styling. No further configuration needed.

You can then [import a SCSS file from `preview.js`](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/configure/styling-and-css#importing-css-files):

```
import "./global.scss";
```