# TypeError: this.getOptions is not a function

Tags: vue.js, webpack, sass-loader

I am facing a weird error when I installed [Bootstrap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_%28front-end_framework%29). The error is below. I tried uninstalling less-loader and installing less-loader@5.0.0, because I saw it online, but it did nothing. I am unsure what to do at this step.

> Syntax Error: TypeError: this.getOptions is not a function

```
 @ ./node_modules/vue-style-loader??ref--8-oneOf-1-0!./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--8-oneOf-1-1!./node_modules/vue-loader-v16/dist/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--8-oneOf-1-2!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--8-oneOf-1-3!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader-v16/dist??ref--0-1!./src/App.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=7ba5bd90&lang=scss 4:14-419 14:3-18:5 15:22-427
 @ ./src/App.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=7ba5bd90&lang=scss
 @ ./src/App.vue
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://192.168.1.182:8080&sockPath=/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js
```

Comment: It would be great if you could add the steps that need to be taken to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 704, accepted):

Similar to what @KostDM said, in my case it seems like `sass-loader@11.0.0` doesn't work with `vue@2.6.12`.

I installed `sass-loader@10.1.1` and it worked like a charm again.

In your `package.json`:

```json
"sass-loader": "^10",
```

Comment: v11 does not work with Vue because v11 requires Webpack v5 -> https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader/releases/tag/v11.0.0

Comment: still not working for me and I'm using vue 3

Comment: @TiletiSaiTejaReddy just try downgrading your sass-loader by changing the version in your package.json to 10.1.1 and run npm install. Try restarting the server again. Worked for me.

Comment: I got the same error for exports-loader because that one requires Webpackv5 as well. I fixed this by downgrading to exports-loader@1.1.1

Comment: [The most copied answer on Stack Overflow with plain text](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/04/19/how-often-do-people-actually-copy-and-paste-from-stack-overflow-now-we-know/) (no code)...

Comment: with yarn `yarn add --dev 'sass-loader@<11'`

Comment: I was actually having issue with storybook, and downgrading `sass-loader` to `^10` did the trick for me.

Comment: As here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70281346/node-js-sass-version-7-0-0-is-incompatible-with-4-0-0-5-0-0-6-0-0 you can remove node-sass and install sass if you are using new versions of vue. Work like a charm.

Comment: Had the same issue with storybook-react, downgrading to sass-loader@10 fixed it

Comment: The Nuxt document is all you need to pay attention to:
https://nuxtjs.org/docs/directory-structure/assets/#sass

Answer (score 102):

I had the same problem **resolved** by downgrading sass-loader to 10.1.1.  I am using @vue/cli 4.5.8 that includes webpack@4.46.0.

From v11.0.0 of sass-loader and v8.0.0 of less-loader, the

> minimum supported webpack version is 5

- [sass-loader v11.0.0 release notes](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader/releases/tag/v11.0.0)
- [less-loader v8.0.0 release
  notes](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/less-loader/releases/tag/v8.0.0)

Comment: Thanks for the hint, helped me to resolve my issue with Storybook and Next.js.

Comment: This answer is a duplicate of the accepted one by D_Pain

Comment: Can you use webpack 5 with vue2?

Comment: @Mathijs Yes, you can use the official [vue-cli](https://cli.vuejs.org/) version 5 to scaffold a project, which uses webpack 5. Or something else like [vue-webpack-starter](https://github.com/itacode/vue-webpack-starter).

Answer (score 63):

Downgrading the sass-loader to ^10.0.0 worked for me, but on a fresh [Nuxt.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuxt.js) CLI application I had to also install Sass with:

```
npm i sass
```

To downgrade, you can remove the `node_modules` folder and to add, run this in your terminal:

```
npm i sass-loader@10
```

This will install the newest 10 version of sass-loader.

And after all, again install all dependencies:

```
npm i
```

Sass-loader versions higher than 10th requires webpack 5

Comment: i just had to remove the sas-loader folder and then run npm i sass-loader@10

Comment: This answer is a duplicate of the accepted one by D_Pain

Comment: Did you see mentioning of nuxt and sass package in D_Pain answer? Srsly?

Answer (score 38):

For me it helped to downgrade postcss-loader

```
+ "postcss-loader": "^4.2.0",
- "postcss-loader": "^5.0.0",
```

Answer (score 30):

Yesterday I found a problem after upgrading sass-loader to the latest version.

If using yarn, you can downgrade sass-loader. Use
**yarn add sass-loader@^10.1.1** it work.

Comment: Solved my problem in a Rails 6.0.1 app. I'm adding my comment here because the console syntax here is what you "normally" use for a recent Rails app. Thank you @D_Pain. I'm not using Vue BTW, but I must have upgraded node modules and caused a problem. Mainly Bootstrap didn't work.

Comment: This answer is a duplicate of the accepted one by D_Pain

Answer (score 26):

style-loader v3 also dropped support for Webpack 4.

Your `package.json` entry should look like this:

`"style-loader": "^2.0.0"`

Answer (score 24):

I had the same problem here with css-loader v6. Downgrading to v5 seems to work:

```
"css-loader": "^5.1.1"
```

Answer (score 16):

This solved for me, for similar problem with [Sass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sass_%28stylesheet_language%29):

1. add to package.json in devDependencies: "sass-loader": "7.3.1",
2. `npm i -D sass` or `yarn add sass --dev`
3. remove node_modules
4. `npm install` or `yarn` depending on your package manager

My configuration:

```json
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "sass": "^1.32.6",
    "sass-loader": "7.3.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
  },
```

Comment: You can replace `npm install && yarn install` with simply `yarn`

Comment: Isn't npm install enough?

Comment: This answer is a duplicate of the accepted one by D_Pain

Answer (score 8):

Ran `yarn remove sass-loader`

And then installed specifically version 10 as `yarn add sass-loader@10`.
This totally solved the issue in `"vue": "~2.6.12",`

Comment: This answer is a duplicate of the accepted one by D_Pain

Comment: Yeah, that's true, but in most cases people are confused by changes in versions, that's whay I wanted to clearly show the version that accepted answer was functioning very right

Answer (score 2):

The same here. Downgrading to the following versions helped:

```
"sass": "^1.38.0",
"sass-loader": "^10.2.0",
```

Comment: This answer is a duplicate of the accepted one by D_Pain

Answer (score 2):

We had an issue with different versions, and the below combination worked:

File: *package.json*

```
{
    "devDependencies": {

        "webpack": "^4.46.0",
        "css-loader": "^5.1.1",

        "babel-loader": "8.1.0",
        "file-loader": "^6.1.0",
        "json-loader": "^0.5.7",
        "postcss-loader": "^6.2.1",
        "raw-loader": "^4.0.1",
        "sass-loader": "^12.6.0",
        "source-map-loader": "^3.0.1",
        "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
        "svg-url-loader": "^6.0.0",
        "ts-loader": "^5.3.3",
        "url-loader": "^4.1.1"
    }
}
```

File: *webpack.config.js*

```
module.exports = {
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: "css-loader",
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The command `yarn add sass-loader` installs version 11, which happens not to be compatible with Webpack version 4 and below. The current Vue CLI V4 uses Webpack v4.

You will have to wait until Vue CLI V5 (will use Webpack 5) is released (currently in Beta) in order to use sass-loader v12.
Alternatively, you can update to Webpack 5, but be sure to read the CHANGELOG.

Comment: This answer is a duplicate of the accepted one by D_Pain

Comment: not a duplicate and actually a better answer

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was struggling to compile *node-sass* on a [CentOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS) 7, and I solved it by removing *node-sass* and adding *sass* instead:

```
npm uninstall node-sass
npm install sass
npm install sass-loader^8
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks [to itacode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66082397/typeerror-this-getoptions-is-not-a-function/66111894#66111894), we just need to do:

That `-D` means only the development environment, and you can remove it for all environments.

[Yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/):

```
# yarn add @vue/cli@^4
yarn add -D sass
yarn add -D less
yarn add -D sass-loader@^10
yarn add -D less-loader@^7
```

Or npm:

```
# npm i @vue/cli@^4
npm i -D sass
npm i -D less
npm i -D sass-loader@^10
npm i -D less-loader@^7
```

Answer (score 0):

When using Webpack version 4, the default in Vue CLI 4. You need to make sure your loaders are compatible with it. Otherwise you will get errors about conflicting peer dependencies. In this case you can use an older version of the loader that is still compatible with Webpack 4.

```
# Sass
npm install -D sass-loader@^10 sass
```

Still not working?

Delete folder *node_modules*

```
npm install
```

[Know more](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/css.html#pre-processors)

Comment: This answer is a duplicate of the accepted one by D_Pain

Answer (score 0):

NPM downloads dependency packages to modules inside the module if they are in a different version than one in your *package.json*, but sometimes it downloads the latest version or dependent package (I don't know why) into a module...

For example, you can have `sass-loader: 2.X` in your *package.json*, and a module XXXX which also has `sass-loader: *` in its dependency packages (you can check that in *package.json* inside that XXXX module).

npm will download `sass-loader 2.X` for you, and `sass-loader: 3.X` for the XXXX package - you’ll get an error.

A quick fix is to remove that additional package from `XXXX/node_modules`.
You can also check what package version the `XXXX` module use and try to use the same version in your project.

In my case *font-awesome-sass-loader@2.0.1* with *project.json*:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "css-loader": "*",
    "sass-loader": "*",
    "style-loader": "*"
  },
```

downloaded `sass-loader: 3.0.0`.

While npm downloaded sass-loader: 2.0.0 according to project.json in my project:

`"style-loader": "2.0.0"`

I removed `node_modules/font-awesome-sass-loader/node_modules/` and it fixed the problem.

Comment: How about just removing the whole node_modules/ folder and re-install them all?

Answer (score 0):

I have add these lines and my code working fine,
Please try this and add or remove your package and version accordingly.

```
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "node-sass": "^7.0.1",
    "sass-resources-loader": "^2.1.0",
    "vue": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.13",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.13",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.13",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.3",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "prettier": "^1.19.1",
    "sass-loader": "^10.0.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
  },
```