# Vue cli using webpack 4 instead of 5 by default

Tags: javascript, webpack, vuejs2

I am trying to get an app up and running with Vue 2 and everything was fine until I tried using the `node-sass` and `sass-loader` packages. I started getting errors and after investigation, it looks like I need to be using `webpack` 5+ for the latest `node-sass` package to work. After poking around it looks like when I created the project it defaulted to `webpack` version 4.46.0.

I updated my `vue-cli` to the latest version as per the instructions on the official page and then tried re-initializing a new project and still have the same issue. Currently, I have `@vue/cli 4.5.12` which looks to be the latest (I think).

I am initializing the app with `vue create <app-name>` and I am using the default configs. I did find [this](https://next.cli.vuejs.org/migrations/migrate-from-v4.html#upgrade-all-plugins-at-once) page which says "migrating from v4" which perhaps implies there might be a higher version of `vue-cli` but again I followed all the instructions to no avail, so not sure if I am just missing something here.

I am pretty novice in Vue and not sure what additional info I should provide to make this useful, but I've searched all over and for the life of me cannot figure out what is going on.

Comment: Same exact issue

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From what I found out on GitHub, the latest stable version - 4.5.12 - of Vue CLI still uses Webpack 4: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/blob/v4.5.12/package.json .
Considering that, the easiest solution in my opinion would be to just downgrade sass-loader to version 10 with `npm install sass-loader@10` for example, as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66087132/1505369.

You could try using a beta version of vue-cli, as I tried, by updating both `@vue/cli-service` and, I believe, all the vue-cli plugins to version 5.0.0-beta.0, with `npm install @vue/cli-service@5.0.0-beta.0 @vue/cli-plugin-babel@5.0.0-beta.0 @vue/cli-plugin-eslint@5.0.0-beta.0 @vue/cli-plugin-vuex@5.0.0-beta.0`. It should end up installing and using Webpack 5. For me personally though, it hasn't really solved the issue, as the new error occurred:

> ERROR  TypeError: The 'compilation' argument must be an instance of
> Compilation TypeError: The 'compilation' argument must be an instance
> of Compilation
> // ...

Comment: Installing the highest 10.x sass-loader version did the trick and it seems like the most hassle-free way. I didn't realize that Webpack 5 was not yet supported by the latest stable version of Vue CLI, so thank you for pointing that out. This saves me a lot of time of trying to figure out what I was doing wrong.

Comment: @djvaroli, great! I'm really glad it helped. Thanks for the message!