# TypeError: this.getOptions is not a function unsolved

Tags: vue.js, sass-loader

I installed sass loader. At first, sas-loader version was 12. Then I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66082397/typeerror-this-getoptions-is-not-a-function). Now tried "sass-loader": "^10.2.0", but still error remained.

> error  in ./src/App.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=scss&
> Syntax Error: TypeError: this.getOptions is not a function

```
> @ ./node_modules/vue-style-loader??ref--8-oneOf-1-0!./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--8-oneOf-1-1!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--8-oneOf-1-2!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--8-oneOf-1-3!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/App.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=scss& 4:14-416 15:3-20:5 16:22-424
 @ ./src/App.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=scss&
 @ ./src/App.vue
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://192.168.31.176:8080&sockPath=/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js
```

What the problem going on?

Comment: And you're really sure the version has been updated? (Check in node_modules)

Comment: in package.json file, it shows 
"sass": "^1.35.2",
    "sass-loader": "^10.2.0",

Comment: After restarting, its error is gone, thanks for