# How to use SCSS in vue.js component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, sass

I am using vue2. in my components i am not able to use scss. showing this compile error.
[image]

[image]

Comment: did you follow the instructions "to install it" ?

Comment: @Bravo Yes, i already install all packages

Comment: One issue is you are scoping it.... and targeting body. you cant target the body in a scope since vue does not instantiate until inside the body. I cant help you further until you fix that.

Comment: @MichaelMano still facing same issue after change class instead of body tag.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66087132/12570655) may help you