# Type Error: this.getOptions is not a function For style-loader

Tags: reactjs, webpack, storybook, webpack-style-loader

**Problem**

While using Storybook, I am running `npm run storybook` and getting the error below.

```
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/style-loader/dist/cjs.js):
TypeError: this.getOptions is not a function
```

**Background/Context**

My goal is to get Storybook to be able to work with `sass`.

The setup is a simple one: I have `scss` files that get imported by the component file.

In looking up ways to accomplish this, I came across an *addon* to be able to do so, see [this](https://github.com/storybookjs/presets/tree/master/packages/preset-scss).  Essentially, you can run `npm i --save-dev @storybook/preset-scss style-loader css-loader sass-loader`.

In doing so, I encountered my first error.  It was the same error, but for `sass-loader`.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66082397/typeerror-this-getoptions-is-not-a-function) Stack Overflow thread helped me fix that error.

So, I guess in summary, I've tried:

- Following along with the docs (linked above)
- Following along with the Stack Overflow thread (linked above)

**Relevant Dev Dependencies**

```
"@storybook/preset-scss": "^1.0.3",
"css-loader": "^6.2.0",
"sass-loader": "^10.1.1",
"style-loader": "^3.2.1"
```

Thanks ahead of time!

Answer (score 79, accepted):

**Solution**

After taking a step back, I realized that I could try out what I did to fix the `sass-loader` issue: **downgrading major versions**.

**Steps**

- Downgraded `style-loader` 1 major version to `2.0.0`: `npm i style-loader@2.0.0`
- Then, as luck would have it, I ran into the same issue with `css-loader`
- Downgraded `css-loader` 1 major version to `5.2.7`: `npm i css-loader@5.2.7`

**Summary**

By downgrading all of the loaders one major version, I was able to get it to work.

Comment: downgrading just style-loader got it to work for me. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! A combination of this answer and this thread helped: https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/12464

Comment: @BryanGuillen May i know which versions of webpack you were using? I tried the same version combination of those loaders but it was not working. Mine is webpack 3.0.0

Comment: @MaanasHegde, that is a great question.  Unfortunately, I do not have access to that code base anymore, and thus, do not remember the webpack version.

Comment: Love you man. It worked for me.

Comment: Yup, downgrading style-loader and css-loader to versions mentioned in this post worked for me as well. Thanks homies!

Answer (score 36):

I was also running into this issue when setting up sass in storybook. The yarn script the readme provides will install the latest versions of those libraries which are no longer compatible with webpack 4 which is what storybook runs on.

For anyone else running into that issue with storybook, this is what you can run instead.

```
yarn add -D @storybook/preset-scss css-loader@5.2.6 sass sass-loader@10.1.1 style-loader@2.0.0
```

Comment: The key dependency for me was the style-loader@2.0.0. All the rest was optional.

Answer (score 4):

The older webpack doesn't support the latest versions of CSS loaders:

```
yarn add -D @storybook/preset-scss css-loader@5.2.6 sass sass-loader@10.1.1 style-loader@2.0.0
```

this has worked for me.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32279527)

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of an [earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68793058/).

Answer (score 1):

After downgrading,
In my case I solved it just commenting the loaders scss and sass:

```
{
                test: /\.css$/,
                use:
                    [
                        {
                            loader: 'style-loader'
                        },
                        {
                            loader: 'css-loader',
                            options: {
                                importLoaders: 1,
                                modules: true
                            }
                        }
                        // ,
                        // {
                        //     loader: 'sass-loader'
                        // }
                        // ,
                        // {
                        //     loader: 'scss-loader'
                        // }
                    ]
            }
```

The declare module "*.module.css"; did not affected the result.

**REMEMBER: Always run**

```
npm start
```

to test these configuration changes to see if something happens**.
Doing this would save me this afternoon.

Comment: Downgrading "style-loader": "^3.3.1" to "style-loader": "^2.0.0" solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't using Storybooks, just Webpack with TS. All I had to do was run the command:

`yarn add -D css-loader@5.2.6 style-loader@2.0.0`

Then, I **removed** scss/sass loader from my webpack config, setting it like this:

```
      {
        test: /\.(css)$/,
        loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
```

Hope that helps anyone.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same error on my react app-

```
    ERROR in ./src/css/main.css
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/style-loader/dist/cjs.js):
TypeError: getValidate(...) is not a function
    at Object.getOptions (D:\RND\React-webpack\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:587:19)
    at Object.loader (D:\RND\React-webpack\node_modules\style-loader\dist\index.js:19:24)
 @ ./src/index.js 4:0-24
```

I had resolved this by following commands:
First I had run a command `npm ls`
I got bellow suggestion:

```
npm ERR! missing: schema-utils@3.1.1, required by webpack@5.76.3
```

So, I have installed schema-utils@3.1.1

```
npm i schema-utils@3.1.1 --save-dev
```

This has removed the error with `getValidate(...) is not a function`