# Rails 6 + Postcss + webpack: TypeError: this.getOptions is not a function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, postcss

When I run my web app :

Failed to compile.

```
./app/javascript/css/application.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--7-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--7-2!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--7-3!./app/javascript/css/application.scss)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
TypeError: this.getOptions is not a function
    at Object.loader (/Users/ben/code/Tioneb/railsapp/node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/index.js:40:24)
```

The package.json looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "blog",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@fullhuman/postcss-purgecss": "^4.0.3",
    "@hotwired/turbo-rails": "^7.0.0-beta.5",
    "@rails/actioncable": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/activestorage": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/ujs": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/webpacker": "4.3.0",
    "@tailwindcss/aspect-ratio": "^0.3.0",
    "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.3.4",
    "@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.4.1",
    "autoprefixer": "^9",
    "postcss": "^8.3.11",
    "postcss-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "stimulus": "^2.0.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^2.2.19"
  },
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2"
  }
}
```

app/javascript/pack/application.js:

```
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")

import "components/prism"
require("../css/application.scss")
```

app/javascript/css/application.scss:

```
@import "tailwindcss/base";
@import "tailwindcss/components";
@import "tailwindcss/utilities";
```

/postccs.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    require('tailwindcss')('./tailwind.config.js'),
    require('autoprefixer'),
    require('postcss-import'),
    require('postcss-flexbugs-fixes'),
    require('postcss-preset-env')({
      autoprefixer: {
        flexbox: 'no-2009'
      },
      stage: 3
    })
  ]
}
```

I tried different version of packages, different setups, however, nothing seems to be working.

Any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: Does this fix your issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66082397/typeerror-this-getoptions-is-not-a-function

Comment: No, I tried it but always the same error ☹️