# Webpack and vue version conflict

Tags: javascript, vue.js, version-control

I'm currently trying to revive a 2 year old Vue project I did. The project is quite small so it shouldn't be too hard but once i run npm run serve I get this error

```
 error  in ./src/components/SideBar.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=3eca7188&lang=less&scoped=true&

Syntax Error: TypeError: this.getOptions is not a function


 @ ./node_modules/vue-style-loader??ref--11-oneOf-1-0!./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--11-oneOf-1-1!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--11-oneOf-1-2!./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--11-oneOf-1-3!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--1-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/components/SideBar.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=3eca7188&lang=less&scoped=true& 4:14-465 15:3-20:5 16:22-473
 @ ./src/components/SideBar.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=3eca7188&lang=less&scoped=true&
 @ ./src/components/SideBar.vue
 @ ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--1-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/App.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
 @ ./src/App.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
 @ ./src/App.vue
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://192.168.1.178:8080&sockPath=/sockjs-node ./node_modules/@vue/cli-service/node_modules/webpack/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js
```

Once I run `npm ls webpack` this is the error I get

```
news-map@0.1.0 /Users/naeemujeeb/Downloads/globalcondition-main
├─┬ @vue/cli-service@4.5.15
│ └── webpack@4.46.0 
└── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY webpack@4.46.0
```

This is currently running on `vue@2.6.14` 
If someone could help I would really appreciate this because I have been trying to fix this problem for a long time

Thank you for any help

Comment: Depending on the NPM version you're using, you may have some unmet peer dependency. You could either install them manually (there should also be a global flag for that one), try to run the whole thing in yarn to have something more verbose, try to get the same Node.js version (+npm) as 2 years ago and maybe kick your lock file + generate a new one with `npm i`.

Comment: Always check the error before asking. Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66082397/typeerror-this-getoptions-is-not-a-function