# What's the fix for Error: Node Sass version 8.0.0 is incompatible with ^4.0.0?

Tags: node-sass

So, I had used sass before using `npm install node-sass` for my reactjs project. I'm now working on a new project and wanted to use sass again. With the same syntax `npm install node-sass` to get it installed, I continued to get

```
./src/components/Main.scss (./node_modules/css-loader??ref--6-oneOf-5-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--6-oneOf-5-3!./src/components/Main.scss)
Error: Node Sass version 8.0.0 is incompatible with ^4.0.0.
```

Or

```
to import sass files, you first need to install node-sass. run `npm install node-sass` or `yarn add node-sass` inside your workspace
...
...
```

I followed the instructions to have sass installed from the links [npmjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass)
[sass-lang](https://sass-lang.com/install)
using these syntaxes

```
brew install sass/sass/sass
```

```
npm install -g sass
```

but I'm still encountering either errors I mentioned earlier.

I tried deleting the node-module folder, package-lock.json and reinstalled node-modules. That still did not fix the error. Also, I followed how others got around fixing Node Sass version 5.0.0||6.0.0|| 7.0.0 incompatibility issue but that did not fix mine.

I'm seeking help now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: 'node-sass' version 5.0.0 is incompatible with ^4.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64625050/error-node-sass-version-5-0-0-is-incompatible-with-4-0-0)

Comment: Nice! I have this exact error right now and I have been checking.

Comment: @disinfor I had it before but it did not help

Answer (score 77):

## Don't use `node-sass` anymore

`node-sass` is now deprecated. You can easily fix it by the following.

```
npm uninstall node-sass
npm install sass
```

It works fully the same with better stability, You will not need to make any additional changes.

And all Works well !

#### But if you still prefer to use `node-sass`

You can use the following table to install the appropriate version `node-sass` for your installed Node.js version which you can check by the command `node --version`.

```
npm install node-sass@(your version)
```

[image]

Comment: Doing this:
npm uninstall node-sass
npm install sass
Just asks for node-sass again.

Comment: To import Sass files, you first need to install node-sass. Error after uninstalling

Comment: @Nickj maybe clear `node-sass` from your `package.json` file

Comment: @Abraham The problem was react scripts no longer includes node-sass so you have to do a multitude of steps to get the processing back. The easiest solution is not to use the latest version of react-scripts sadly.

Comment: This should be the Accepted Answer. It definitely solves the issue by switching to the sass package. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

You can follow these two steps:

1. Uninstall your node-sass:
   `npm uninstall node-sass`
2. Install old version node-sass:
   `npm install --save-dev  --unsafe-perm node-sass@4.14.1`

It's okay now

Answer (score 5):

update `sass-loader`, or remove and install again.

Comment: Thank you..... What ended up working for me is doing 
```
npm uninstall node-sass
npm install node-sass
change the "react-scripts": "4.0.0" into "react-scripts": "4.0.3" in package.json and save
npm install
npm start
``` 
I got it from 
[www.codegrepper.com](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/javascript/Error%3A+Node+Sass+version+5.0.0+is+incompatible+with+%5E4.0.0.)

Comment: also depends on which VueJS version you use, for 2.6.x you cannot use today's version of sass-loader (12), you must stick to v10 --> `sass-loader@^10`. credits to @D_Pain on [its answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66082397/typeerror-this-getoptions-is-not-a-function).

Answer (score 3):

Try this: In your packege.json file, delete "node-sass": "^4.12.0" and replace it with "sass": "". This did it for me.

Answer (score 1):

The answer for me was to update react-scripts to 4.0.3. I couldn't do the latest version of react-scripts because it still requires a bunch of hacks to make packages work that had polyfilled modules automatically loaded before.