# Getting error of this in reactjs and tried a lot of commands but still my issue is not resolved

Tags: reactjs, sass, node-sass

./src/components/navBar/style.scss (./node_modules/css-loader??ref--6-oneOf-5-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--6-oneOf-5-3!./src/components/navBar/style.scss)
Error: Node Sass version 9.0.0 is incompatible with ^4.0.0.

Tried every command which were on stack overflow please find out a way.

Comment: Look at this answer: [What's the fix for Error: Node Sass version is incompatible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74501317/whats-the-fix-for-error-node-sass-version-8-0-0-is-incompatible-with-4-0-0)