# Node Sass version 9.0.0 is incompatible with ^4.0.0

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, webpack, sass

I do not have node-sass or sass package installed in my app. But i keep getting this error me

```
ERROR in ./src/scss/styles.scss (./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/plugins/raw-css-loader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??embedded!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--15-3!./src/scss/styles.scss)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):
Error: Node Sass version 9.0.0 is incompatible with ^4.0.0.
    at getRenderFuncFromSassImpl (C:\Users\Documents\Repositories-GitHub\IDM_157256_device-hierarchy-ui\node_modules\sass-loader\lib\loader.js:108:19)
    at Object.sassLoader (C:\Users\Documents\Repositories-GitHub\IDM_157256_device-hierarchy-ui\node_modules\sass-loader\lib\loader.js:46:20)
ERROR in ./node_modules/@accelerate/prime-ng/resources/themes/gm/theme.scss (./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/plugins/raw-css-loader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??embedded!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--15-3!./node_modules/@accelerate/prime-ng/resources/themes/gm/theme.scss)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):
Error: Node Sass version 9.0.0 is incompatible with ^4.0.0.
    at getRenderFuncFromSassImpl (C:\Users\Documents\Repositories-GitHub\IDM_157256_device-hierarchy-ui\node_modules\sass-loader\lib\loader.js:108:19)
    at Object.sassLoader (C:\Users\Documents\Repositories-GitHub\IDM_157256_device-hierarchy-ui\node_modules\sass-loader\lib\loader.js:46:20)
ERROR in ./src/app/app.component.scss
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):
Error: Node Sass version 9.0.0 is incompatible with ^4.0.0.
    at getRenderFuncFromSassImpl (C:\Users\Documents\Repositories-GitHub\IDM_157256_device-hierarchy-ui\node_modules\sass-loader\lib\loader.js:108:19)
    at Object.sassLoader (C:\Users\Documents\Repositories-GitHub\IDM_157256_device-hierarchy-ui\node_modules\sass-loader\lib\loader.js:46:20)
ERROR in ./src/app/components/home/home.component.scss
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):
Error: Node Sass version 9.0.0 is incompatible with ^4.0.0.
    at getRenderFuncFromSassImpl (C:\Users\Documents\Repositories-GitHub\IDM_157256_device-hierarchy-ui\node_modules\sass-loader\lib\loader.js:108:19)
    at Object.sassLoader (C:\Users\Documents\Repositories-GitHub\IDM_157256_device-hierarchy-ui\node_modules\sass-loader\lib\loader.js:46:20)
ERROR in ./src/app/components/mast/mast.component.scss
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):
Error: Node Sass version 9.0.0 is incompatible with ^4.0.0.
    at getRenderFuncFromSassImpl (C:\Users\Documents\Repositories-GitHub\IDM_157256_device-hierarchy-ui\node_modules\sass-loader\lib\loader.js:108:19)
    at Object.sassLoader (C:\Users\Documents\Repositories-GitHub\IDM_157256_device-hierarchy-ui\node_modules\sass-loader\lib\loader.js:46:20)
```

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "@accelerate/prime-ng-quick-start",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@accelerate/prime-ng": "0.0.47",
    "@angular/animations": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "^8.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^8.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^8.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^8.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^8.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^8.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^8.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^8.2.0",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.3",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "css-element-queries": "^1.2.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "ng-mocks": "^9.0.0",
    "normalize.css": "^8.0.1",
    "primeflex": "^1.0.0",
    "primeicons": "^2.0.0",
    "primeng": "^8.1.1",
    "quill": "^1.3.7",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.2",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.4",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.802.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^8.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.3.10",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.6",
    "@types/node": "^11.11.3",
    "codelyzer": "^5.2.2",
    "jasmine": "^3.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "^5.4.2",
    "ts-node": "^8.0.3",
    "tslint": "^5.16.0",
    "typescript": "^3.5.3"
  }
}
```

There is no node-sass or sass in my package.json. And the weird thing is that, my friend is using the same version of everything as I am like: node, cli, env variables etc and his is working just fine but I am seeing these error I cannot figure out why am I getting this error. I do not want to install any other packages since i know that its already working on my friend's machine.

Comment: Some of your dependencies have their own dependencies and node-sass is certainly over there

Comment: I see thank you for answering that, but how is it possible that its working just fine on my friend's machine but not mine. Do you have any suggestion that I can try? thank you!

Comment: your packages are resolved by NPM separately, right? You did not take the package-lock.json file from your friend?

When NPM resolved package versions on your machine it took the newest packages versions (^ allows to take the highest minor version of a package). And Probably thats why you other package versions resolved.

Comment: no i did not use my friend's package-lock,json file. But installing "node-sass": "^4.14.1" on my machine worked. not sure why my friend did not have to install any node-sass to make it work. But its finally working for me after installing node-sass.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the fix for Error: Node Sass version 8.0.0 is incompatible with ^4.0.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74501317/whats-the-fix-for-error-node-sass-version-8-0-0-is-incompatible-with-4-0-0)

Answer (score 0):

If it works for you frend you can follow one of this scenarios:

1. take `package-lock.json` file from your friend and run `npm ci`
2. delete all `^` (or replace them with `~`) from all versions in `package.json` file and run `npm i`

In general be aware of these:

1. what `npm i` and `npm ci` do
2. what `^` and `~` do while resolving package versions from scratch (`npm i`)